# why didn't i get the referer parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

My related Request handling code as following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String customer(ModelMap modelMap , @RequestParam Integer age) {
   modelMap.addAttribute("requestKey", "Hola!");
   modelMap.addAttribute("age", age);
   return "cust";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/request" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(ModelMap modelMap , @RequestParam(value = "age" , required = false)Integer age) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("requestKey", "Hola!");
        modelMap.addAttribute("age", age);
        return "request";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/request" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String responseBody(ModelMap modelMap , final @RequestBody Student student){
modelMap.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
modelMap.addAttribute("lastname", student.getLastname());
modelMap.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
return "request";
    }
```

**cust.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>${age}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**request.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RequestBody</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            JSONTest = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "customer",
                    type: "get",
                    data: {
                        name: "Okan",
                        lastname: "Pehlivan",
                        age:22 },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>${requestKey}</p>
        <h1>My jQuery JSON Web Page</h1>
        <div id="resultDivContainer"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()">JSON</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to get request using ajax, and i have some parameters, (name=Okan e.g). I want to show any patameter on the cust.jsp. When i debug the code for welcome() metod, age assigned the my age. I mapped this value with its key "age". request.jsp file is not changed.

Comment: could you elaborate what you are expecting in your request.jsp it's referer or age value or both??

Comment: with button, i want to send request /request with parameter, and get this patameter in cust.jsp. i'll edit my request.jsp file

Comment: What you are getting in age value in welcome() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax call will not change the view. It will return the parameters on same page in success : function(response) {} . If you wants to change the view, you need make non ajax GET call on a separate method and pass inline parameters like:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer/{name}/{lastname}/{age}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customer(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name, @PathVariable(value = "lastname") String lastname, @PathVariable(value = "age") String age) {
       //code here
        return "cust";
    }
```

**JSP**

```
window.open("/customer/Okan/Pehlivan/22 ","_self");
```

It will return on cust.jsp

Answer (score 0):

The request jsp is not changed because you are not changing it anywhere on the page after the AJAX call.
You do make a request but are not using the response.
Add a success function to your ajax call and then read the data there.
For example :

`$.ajax({
url, data , dataType and method as is with an addition of the following : 
success : function(responseText){
  Set responseText to your <p>
}
});`

For showing the age in cust.jsp, the request parameter needs to be passed while calling the url. something like : http://host-path/context-path/customer?age=69

Autoboxing should take care of `int` to `Integer` conversion for request parameter, if you see an exception try using `int` instead.

Some info that might be of help :

- When using ${varName} in jsp / javascript, you need the model to
  already have that data.
- Consider using  tags to control the out put of dynamic
  variables, they may help.
- When making ajax calls to request for data, process the response in a
  handler and continue your logic from there.

HTH.